# UITextView in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am creating textview(editable) through coding in uitableview in cellforrowatindexpath delegate. textview is showing in every row correctly. the problem is that when i am enter text in textview and scroll the tableview, then text disappear from textview. if anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are adding a different textview to each of the different reusable cells.  If you have, say, 6 cells visible at any time, then you need 6 different textviews.

It sounds like when you scroll, your textview gets used for another cell.

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MyTableCell *cell = (MyListTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {      
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:/** put appropriate rect here **/] autorelease];
        // create other cell structures you need
    }


    // Set up the cell...
}
```

Comment: hi, i have 25 rows in a tableview, & i am creating only one textview in cellforrowatindexpath delegate. how'll i got my textview separate for each cell. how'll i get rid of this.

Comment: You need to create different TextViews.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to edit the text in the textview, the text scrolls up so that the top of the textview is where the new text will appear when typed. Try swiping down on the textview to reveal the previous info.